# Present iPhone application to the Board

Tags: iphone

We have a new app for the iPhone which is to be presented to the Board. I am asking if anyone has any ideas for the most effective way to present using the actual device.

In reality the device is the most impractical platform to present with to a large room, but in this case it will be required. So if S.Jobs can manage it there must be an easy solution for this type of thing.

Is RDP the only way or is there something better?

Have you done this type of thing and can offer some advise?

Comment: As a follow-up to this question, I've found some information for iPhone App mirroring (http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3). Wonder why Apple never made this a system function instead of app-specific and an unpublished part of the API.

Answer (score 1):

yeah iphone can display videos on your tv/display but iphone is different then all ipods before. you have to get special component wire for iphone to view your videos on tv. its 50 bucks in apple store but u might find some cheaper if u do some search on web.i have that cable and it works great. they probably changed the system of displaying videos because of fact that there is microphone connection in iphone headphone jack. you know... like when you take the wire you said you bought u have left, right sound ( red & white) and video yellow but in fact the parts of 3.5 mm jack which in old ipods is meant for video is meant for microphone in iphone. and i guess its same with ipod touch because when i had touch it wouldn't display videos through old style ipod adapter as well...

Here's the link http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB...ks&mco=MTQ2MjE note that the picture there isnt right. its the component adapter not composite as the picture shows which means green/blue/red for video and red/white audio... hope i helped

Comment: This isn't going to work as specific applications do not mirror their output through the video cable. Each application must enable themselves (in code) to send their output to the video using the private MPTVOutWindow API. I'm not after just playing videos here. I need to mirror an application through the video output for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that cable is going to work for this situation. The video out on the iPhone is mainly for playing pictures or videos. You can't run apps using video out without jailbreaking the device. Since this is an app that you guys wrote, why not hook up a Mac laptop running XCode and use a projector to demo using the iPhone simulator?

Comment: Yes, we've considered that option but the audience are going to want to see the real deal in this case. I couldn't see Steve Jobs getting away with presenting the iPhone to his audience using a simulator.

Comment: Steve Jobs is also the CEO of the company that made the device. Considering they have all the cryptographic keys they can do whatever the hell they want.

Answer (score 1):

@Gerard:  Unfortunately, there is not a way currently to just "plug-in" to the device iPhone/iPod touch.  One of the things you can do is use a digital overhead projector, or an overhead camera and then channel the video output to the desired output (projector, server, etc...).

This is a common tacit used my Apple at their local/on-site developer conferences and tech talks.